# Grouping a list of items based on a space separated list of tags and else

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, exslt

The problem has multiple facets:

1. How to categorize based on specific space separated contents of a tag
2. How to categorize for lack of such specific content.

As an example, take the following data:

```
<messages>
  <m> 
    <subject>message tagged with A B C</subject>
    <tags>A B C</tags>
  </m>

  <m> 
    <subject>message tagged with B C D</subject>
    <tags>B C D</tags>
  </m>

  <m> 
    <subject>message tagged with X Y A</subject>
    <tags>X Y A</tags>
  </m>

  <m> 
    <subject>message tagged with C X</subject>
    <tags>C X</tags>
  </m>

  <m>
    <subject>message tagged with Y</subject>
    <tags>Y</tags>
  </m>

</messages>
```

Given a known set of tags, say

```
<xsl:param name="pKnownTags">
  <t>A</t>
  <t>B</t>
</xsl:param>
```

I want to generate an output that would look like:

```
Messages tagged with A:
* message tagged with A B C
* message tagged with X Y A

Messages tagged with B:
* message tagged with A B C
* message tagged with B C D

Messages tagged with neither:
* message tagged with C X
* message tagged with Y
```

Using EXSLT is fine, but otherwise need 1.0 solution. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't require anything too fancy. Please give the below a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="pKnownTags">
    <t>A</t>
    <t>B</t>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:variable name="pKnownTagsNodeSet" select="exsl:node-set($pKnownTags)/t" />

  <xsl:template match="/messages">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$pKnownTagsNodeSet">
      <xsl:with-param name="docEl" select="." />
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <xsl:text>Messages tagged with none of the above:&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="m" mode="checkAbsence" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="t">
    <xsl:param name="docEl" select="/.." />

    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Messages tagged with ', ., ':&#xA;')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$docEl/m[contains(concat(' ', tags, ' '),
                                                   concat(' ', current(), ' '))]" />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m" mode="checkAbsence">
    <xsl:variable name="currentTagsPadded" select="concat(' ', tags, ' ')" />
    <xsl:apply-templates
          select="(.)[not($pKnownTagsNodeSet[contains($currentTagsPadded,
                                                      concat(' ', ., ' '))]
                         )
                     ]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="m">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('* ', subject, '&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when run on your sample input, this produces:

```
Messages tagged with A:
* message tagged with A B C
* message tagged with X Y A

Messages tagged with B:
* message tagged with A B C
* message tagged with B C D

Messages tagged with none of the above:
* message tagged with C X
* message tagged with Y
```

Comment: Awesome! Couple of follow ups: What is the magic that "docEl" selection? In particular, I tried replacing that with just "/messages"  (remove as parameter, and just use whereever docEl was), and that doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: Firstly, the `select="/.."` doesn't do anything useful here. It's just a failsafe I use for node-set parameters. The reason `$docEl` has to be passed in as a parameter is that the `<t>` elements exist in a different XML document from the input XML. If you evaluate `/message` relative to a `t` element, you will not find anything.

Comment: Thanks! Another question: In <xsl:template match="t"> I replaced contains(...) as contains(tags,current()), i.e removed the concat()s. That seems to render the same output. Under what condition is such concat required? (I saw these seemingly excess concat()s in other places, so I am guessing, that is a more reliable pattern. if so, why?)

Comment: That's another failsafe. It pads the values with spaces to prevent false positives. If `tags` had the value `Hello Goodbye` and `t` had the value `Good`, then `contains(tags, t)` would be `true`, whereas `contains(concat(' ', tags, ' '), concat(' ', t, ' '))` would be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

> Using EXSLT is fine

Well, if your processor supports the EXSLT str:tokenize() function, then this could be quite simple:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl str">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="pKnownTags">
    <t>A</t>
    <t>B</t>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="tags-set" select="exsl:node-set($pKnownTags)/t" />
<xsl:variable name="xml" select="/" />

<xsl:key name="message-by-tags" match="m" use="str:tokenize(tags)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- matching messages -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$tags-set">
        <xsl:variable name="tag" select="." />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Messages tagged with ', $tag, ':&#10;')"/>
        <!-- switch context to source document in order to use key -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$xml">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('message-by-tags', $tag)">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('* ', subject, ':&#10;')"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- non-matching messages -->
    <xsl:text>Messages tagged with none:&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="messages/m[not(str:tokenize(tags)=$tags-set)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('* ', subject)"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```